# Calculating gradient orientation (HOG like) poor accuracy

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, gradient, polar-coordinates, linear-interpolation

I am trying to implement a image matching algorithm based on gradient orientation matching. The main algo contains from the following steps:

[image]

1. convert the image to polar coordinates:

[image]

2. calculate gradients using sobel operator:

   Xgrad = cv2.Sobel(gr,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)

[image]

```
Ygrad = cv2.Sobel(gr,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=3)
```

[image]

3) calculate orientation of gradient and binarize it. :

[image]

Now I can compare images using last features map with ignorance to rotation ans smal changes.

But what I have found that this algo detects rotations of the same image with rotation rather purely. I have build a test image with circles to test this algo:

[image]

and rotated it to 10 grads

[image]

here are polar conversions:

[image]

[image]

and gradient orientation masks: as You se here is already a lot of noise on gradient matrix. and it brokes matching algo.

[image]
[image]

and it's best passing difference mask: the whole line areas are marked as not matched. Small gaussian blurring on different steps are not helping at all. I dont know why.

[image]

**Update:**

**Gradient calculation:**

```
gx = cv2.Sobel(gr,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=1)
gy = cv2.Sobel(gr,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=1)
blurredgx = cv2.GaussianBlur(gx,(11,3),1)
blurredgy = cv2.GaussianBlur(gy,(11,3),1)
magnitude, angle = cv2.cartToPolar(blurredgx, blurredgy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please explain how you've computed orientation of gradients? I believe you've grouped each 4x4 window and computed the orientation of gradients inside each such window. But the sobel operator used has size 5x5. This obviously result in some overlap. Could you explain on this?

Comment: I have added in question my gradient calculation algo. I have tried to play with extra smoothing or without a great success